# Codeigniter alternative to header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am working on a **Register and Login** application with CodeIgniter 3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

I have a "users" MySQL table and a corresponding "users.php" view that renders the "users" table in an HTML format, like the image below illustrates:

[image]

Those "Enable" buttons are links that, when clicked, execute the `activate()` method of the Users controller:

```
public function activate($user_id) {
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');
    $user = $this->Usermodel->activateUser($user_id);
    redirect('users');
}
```

The problem with the last line of the above function, `redirect('users');`, is that if I activate a user on any other page *but* the first, I will not be able to see the user *activated* (because I will be redirected to the first page).

Using `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` instead of `redirect('users');` inside the above function will do the job but:

1. Is it the safest method available?
2. Is there a Codeigniter specific way to do this?

Comment: Store current page in a section. Pass it to php-script with javascript.

Comment: Of course if you activate a user on the first page it will return to the first page and for all other pages as that is the default. As an attempt to speed this up a little, what are you using for your Table/pagination? The trick in this case is you redirect with the same information regarding the page you are on so it will be re-displayed correctly.

Comment: Is it jquery pagination or CodeIgniter ajax pagination??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca load the User agent library and do this as well:

```
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```